# C++ getline forces to close a console application with space

Tags: c++, string, char, getline, c-strings

**The explanation:**

Working with two input streams streams, both use `getline()` to capture the user input. The first `getline()` is called in the `userStringPrompt()` function:

```
string userStringPrompt()
{
    string userString;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, userString);
    return userString;
}
```

That sets a string that the program will use later to perform functions, like count its consonants, its vowels, etc.

The second input is used in the menu selection (choose what function/method to perform on the above string):

```
string userMenuPrompt()
{
    string userString;
    getline(cin, userString);
    return userString;
}
```

This takes in a user input: `A, B, C, D, E` and performs an action. For example, if a user inputs into the first input stream:

> Hello

and then enter "A" in the second input stream, it should count the vowels in *hello*, then return the number from the calculation, e.g. 2

**The issue:**

The program functions correctly when the input in `userStringPrompt` is without spaces. For example, **Hello** works, but **Hello World** would break the application and cause a force close. I'm not sure why, since I am capturing the stream with getline(cin, string).

**The entire code:**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string userStringPrompt();
string userMenuPrompt();
void showMenu();
int countConsonants(string *ptr);
int countVowels(string *ptr);
int countConsonantsVowels(string *ptr);


int main()
{
    string userInput = "";
    string userString;
    bool userStringSet = false;


    while (userInput != "e") {

        if (!userStringSet) {
            userString = userStringPrompt();
            userStringSet = true;
        }

        showMenu();
        userInput = userMenuPrompt();
        string *pointerVariable = &userString;


        if (userInput == "a") {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Vowel count in \"" << userString << "\": " << countVowels(pointerVariable) << endl;
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }

        if (userInput == "b") {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Consonants count in \"" << userString << "\": " << countConsonants(pointerVariable) << endl;
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }

        if (userInput == "c") {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Vowel count in \"" << userString << "\": " << countVowels(pointerVariable) << endl;
            cout << "Consonants count in \"" << userString << "\": " << countConsonants(pointerVariable) << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;
        }

        if (userInput == "d") {
            userStringSet = false;
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

int countConsonants(string *ptr) {
    string getVar = *ptr;
    int stringSize = getVar.length();
    int vowelCount = countVowels(ptr);
    int totalConsonants = stringSize - vowelCount;
    return totalConsonants;
}

int countVowels(string *ptr) {
    int vowelsToCount = 0;
    string stringVar = *ptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < stringVar.length(); i++){
        if (tolower(stringVar[i]) == 'a' || tolower(stringVar[i]) == 'e' || tolower(stringVar[i]) == 'i' || tolower(stringVar[i]) == 'o' || tolower(stringVar[i]) == 'u') {
            vowelsToCount++;
        }
    }

    return vowelsToCount;
}

int countConsonantsVowels(string *ptr) {
    int count = countConsonants(ptr);
    count += countVowels(ptr);
    return count;
}

string userStringPrompt()
{
    string userString;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, userString);
    return userString;
}

string userMenuPrompt()
{
    string userString;
    getline(cin, userString);
    return userString;
}

void showMenu() {
    cout << "A) Count the number of vowels in the stream" << endl;
    cout << "B) Count the number of consonants in the stream" << endl;
    cout << "C) Count both the vowels and consonants in the stream" << endl;
    cout << "D) Enter another string" << endl;
    cout << "E) Exit the program" << endl;
}
```

Any guidance/hints would be greatly appreciated. I'm absolutely confused.

Comment: Works perfectly on my compiler.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I'm currently on MS Visual C++ 2013 ... Wonder if that has something to do with it. 

Were you able to navigate through the menu and count the vowels of the string with a space in it?

Comment: Gcc, codeblocks 13.12

Comment: I tried the code with VS 13, other than the fact that you ask for a upper case letter and expect a lower case the program runs for both `Hello` and `Hello World` input and `a` option

Comment: Interesting, @ZivS, thanks. I'll check into it a little more, but it seems to be working for everyone but me?

Comment: Where does the program crash? Have you tried to debug it? BTW you wrote `when the input in userMenuPrompt is without spaces` did you mean `userStringPrompt`?

Comment: @ZivS It crashes at carriage return, when "entering" the string. And yes, you are correct, I need to change that.

Comment: Post some more information then... Is there an exception? Are you running from VS (Local Debug) or running the exe (Ctrl+F5) ? Release / Debug? more info would be helpful

Comment: @ZivS am using "Local Windows Debugger" as Debug for 32. The debug log shows the following: https://gist.github.com/markbratanov/06f138f1375ccaa7b123

I tried running as release and the same issue occurs. 

I'm trying to debug, currently stepping through the code to get more information.

Comment: I got a warning on this line `for (int i = 0; i < stringVar.length(); i++){` saying that it's trying to check an `unsigned int` with an `signed int`,

Comment: @ArunA.S that's not really anything to worry about, at least not in this case. It's due to the integer returned by string::length() being unsigned, but unless it's a very long string, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your program is not crushing, it's just normally exits.

```
The program '[8776] Chapter10.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

which is ok, no error code returned.

When you run your program it asks for input, do its work and because there is no more work for it - exits. To see the output you can do one of the following:

1. Try to run it with Ctrl + F5 in VS, it will add `pause` command to the end.
2. Another way to run it is to open command line and run it from there.

Also in your case I guess the problem is in `break` statements. When you choose what to do with the string you break your loop (which should run while user enters `e`). Remove all `break`s and it will be fine.